# Java compilation problem, Linux, project from Eclipse re-compile on Linux

Tags: java, linux, compilation

I am trying to recompile an existing Java project exported from Eclipse.  It is necessary to recompile this because I am running simulations remotely on other machines where a different (older) version of Java is installed.  I have tried recompiling my .java file which specifies the simulation in question.  However, it appears that it is necessary to recompile all other classes etc as well. Has anyone got an idea how to do this WITHOUT using Eclipse (I am not the Admin on the other machines and thus Eclipse is unavailable to me) and not manually because the project is quite huge?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: Can't Eclipse export Ant files? (See Ant for compiling, it's a tool like GNUMake, only, well, it's not)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to always have an command line way to build an application. The usual way to do this in Java is using ANT (or Maven).

Answer (score 1):

1. As @Santiago Lezica says, Eclipse can generate an Ant file.
2. I believe that Eclipse allows you to build for an older target platform than the one you are currently running.  That way you can do all of your builds locally.

The second approach has the advantage that you can fix any problems arising from compiling for the older platforms (e.g. use of new language features, use of new classes / methods) from the comfort of your own ... workstation.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option that you should consider: Tell Eclipse to generate code for the old Java version (see the compiler options). That way, you can create code that runs on Java 1.3, even if Eclipse uses Java 5.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  However, the whole point of this is that I would like to compile it on the remote machine.  This is a cluster and thus compiling it there should be better. Especially as I might need to occasionally alter some classes and it would be rather inconvenient if I had to do this elsewhere.

Comment: This isn't C where recompiling the code on the target architecture makes it faster. The classes are already compiled. Why compile them again without any modifications? That just wastes time. The resulting code won't be faster or better since the Java runtime (JIT) will optimize it at runtime; the Java compiler itself doesn't optimize much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your requirements are, but you could set the compiler level for your projects at the (older) level of your Linux installs. This would cause Eclipse to recompile it at that version, instead of a newer version.

At my company we use IBM's Rational Application Developer (instead of pure Eclipse), but I am assuming the option is in the same spot. If you right-click on your project, you can go to the Java Compiler options and then set the compatibility to the level of that on Linux (1.3, 1.4, etc.).

Since compile Java byte-code is supposed to be portable (for the most part), this should get you past most of your problems.

Otherwise, the other option is to use something like Ant or Maven scripts (which can be kicked off by Eclipse) and then just use a property to set the compiler right before you run it. This way you don't have to switch properties on your projects all the time, if you truly do need "newer" compiled code and can't live with "older" code on both systems.

Comment: Thanks, I will try recompiling with Ecplise.  But I guess there should be a way to compile on the remote machine? The Eclipse method is somewhat unsatisfying.

Comment: So I would use what others are suggesting here and use Ant or Maven to build your project. It may not be a bad idea to store the build files with your project. This gives you two advantages: 1) You can now build the project outside of Eclipse on you Linux box. You only need the JDK and Ant or Maven installed and configured. 2) You can tell Eclipse to run your Ant scripts or Maven scripts(if you have m2eclipse plugin installed). Now you are building the same, it is just that you are using Eclipse to kick it off. Makes the most sense to me as the way to go for both systems.